# Unable to create a C++ project in Unreal Engine 5

Tags: c++, .net-core, unreal-engine5

error message:

```
An error occurred while trying to generate project files.
Running C:/Games/UE_5.1/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat -projectfiles -project="C:/UE projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "..\..\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" -projectfiles -project="C:/UE projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' was not found.
- The following frameworks were found:
3.1.20 at [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
The specified framework can be found at:
- https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=x86&rid=win10-x86"
```

I have searched the internet and installed everything
[referred links 1](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/cant-create-c-in-unreal-engine-5/232502)
[referred links 2](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/cant-create-a-new-c-project/479945)

still, the same error is coming, kindly help me pls.

Comment: Have you tried installing the framework at the link you were given?

Comment: @john Yes it resolved it, but now I'm facing this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/76659146/22199867

Comment: I'm afraid I know nothing at all about unreal engine, but clearly you have some kind of versioning issue. I would start again, read **official documentation** only, no random google searches, youtube videos or downloads from random sites.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the IDE you are using:

- **VS Studio** do you have .NET 6.0 Runtime enabled in the Visual Studio installer and also C++ core features
  [image: VS Studio Installer]
- In **Rider** also make sure Toolset and Build settings point to correct .NET version (locations vary depending on where you have your setup, if you expand lists you'll find what you seek for if it's installed, else I propose you install missing)
  [image]

Would also suggest to take a look at official setup documentation, worth double checking:

- https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/setting-up-visual-studio-development-environment-for-cplusplus-projects-in-unreal-engine/
- https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/setting-up-your-project-in-unreal-engine/