# Unable to create a C++ Project in Unreal Engine 5 [error CS0041: 'The version of Windows PDB writer is older than required: ‘diasymreader.dll’’]

Tags: unreal-engine5

I am facing an issue while trying to generate project files in Unreal Engine. The error message and log file are as follows:
Error Message:
An error occurred while trying to generate project files.

Running C:/Games/UE_5.1/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat -projectfiles -project=“C:/UE projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject” -game -rocket -progress
Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet “…..\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll” -projectfiles -project=“C:/UE projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject” -game -rocket -progress
Log file: C:\Users\aanan\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log_GPF.txt

Some Platforms were skipped due to invalid SDK setup: IOS, Android, Linux, LinuxArm64.
See the log file for detailed information

Discovering modules, targets and source code for project…
error CS0041: Unexpected error writing debug information – ‘The version of Windows PDB writer is older than required: ‘diasymreader.dll’’
Expecting to find a type to be declared in a target rules named ‘MyProjectTarget’. This type must derive from the ‘TargetRules’ type defined by Unreal Build Tool.

LOG FILE :

```
Log started at 07/10/2023 23:45:04 (2023-07-10T18:15:04Z)
Adding event matcher: CompileEventMatcher
Adding event matcher: LinkEventMatcher
Adding event matcher: MicrosoftEventMatcher
Adding event matcher: XoreaxEventMatcher
No config file at C:\Users\aanan\OneDrive\Documents\Unreal Engine\UnrealBuildTool\BuildConfiguration.xml
Configuration will be read from:
C:\Users\aanan\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\UnrealBuildTool\BuildConfiguration.xml
Registering build platform: UnrealBuildTool.AndroidPlatformFactory
Note: Android toolchain NDK r25b recommended
Registering build platform: Android - buildable: False
Registering build platform: UnrealBuildTool.IOSPlatformFactory
Registering build platform: IOS - buildable: False
Registering build platform: UnrealBuildTool.LinuxPlatformFactory
Registering build platform: Linux - buildable: False
Registering build platform: LinuxArm64 - buildable: False
Registering build platform: UnrealBuildTool.MacPlatformFactory
Registering build platform: UnrealBuildTool.TVOSPlatformFactory
Registering build platform: UnrealBuildTool.WindowsPlatformFactory
Found Windows 10 SDK root at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10 (1)
Found Windows 10 SDK root at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10 (2)
Found Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.17763.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
Found Universal CRT version 10.0.17763.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
Found Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.18362.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
Found Universal CRT version 10.0.18362.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
Found Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
Found Universal CRT version 10.0.19041.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
Found Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
Found Universal CRT version 10.0.22000.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
Found Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
Found Universal CRT version 10.0.22621.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
Win64 Installed SDK(s): MinVersion_Sdk=10.0.00000.0, MaxVersion_Sdk=10.9.99999.0, CurrentVersion_Sdk=10.0.18362.0, Version_AutoSdk=10.0.18362.0, CurrentVersion_AutoSdk=
Registering build platform: Win64 - buildable: True
Registering build platform: UnrealBuildTool.HoloLensPlatformFactory
Log file: C:\Users\aanan\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log_GPF.txt

Resolved project argument C:/UE projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject to C:\UE projects\MyProject\MyProject.uproject
Registering project generator UnrealBuildTool.AndroidProjectGenerator for Android
Registering project generator UnrealBuildTool.IOSProjectGenerator for IOS
Registering project generator UnrealBuildTool.LinuxProjectGenerator for Linux
Registering project generator UnrealBuildTool.LinuxProjectGenerator for LinuxArm64
Registering project generator UnrealBuildTool.MacProjectGenerator for Mac
Skipping project file generator registration for Mac due to no valid BuildPlatform.
Registering project generator UnrealBuildTool.TVOSProjectGenerator for TVOS
Skipping project file generator registration for TVOS due to no valid BuildPlatform.
Registering project generator UnrealBuildTool.WindowsProjectGenerator for Win64
Registering project generator UnrealBuildTool.HoloLensProjectGenerator for HoloLens
Skipping project file generator registration for HoloLens due to no valid BuildPlatform.

— SDK INFO START —

Some Platforms were skipped due to invalid SDK setup: IOS, Android, Linux, LinuxArm64.
See the log file for detailed information

— SDK INFO END —

Discovering modules, targets and source code for project…
Found Visual Studio installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community (Product=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community, Version=16.11.33801.447)
Found Visual Studio toolchain: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133 (Family=14.29.30133, FamilyRank=0, Version=14.29.30151, Is64Bit=True, Preview=False, Architecture=x64, Error=False, Redist=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.29.30133)
Detected supported platforms: Win64, IOS, Android, Linux, LinuxArm64
Skipping C:\Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Intermediate\Build\BuildRules\UE5Rules.dll: File is installed
Skipping C:\Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Intermediate\Build\BuildRules\UE5ProgramRules.dll: File is installed
Generating target Editor for C:\UE projects\MyProject\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\UE5.vcxproj
Generating target Game for C:\UE projects\MyProject\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\UE5.vcxproj
Creating project rules assembly for C:\UE projects\MyProject\MyProject.uproject…
Found 0 Plugins:
Found 1 Modules:
C:\UE projects\MyProject\Source\MyProject\MyProject.Build.cs
Compiling C:\UE projects\MyProject\Intermediate\Build\BuildRules\MyProjectModuleRules.dll: Assembly does not exist
error CS0041: Unexpected error writing debug information – ‘The version of Windows PDB writer is older than required: ‘diasymreader.dll’’
Expecting to find a type to be declared in a target rules named ‘MyProjectTarget’. This type must derive from the ‘TargetRules’ type defined by Unreal Build Tool.
BuildException: Expecting to find a type to be declared in a target rules named ‘MyProjectTarget’. This type must derive from the ‘TargetRules’ type defined by Unreal Build Tool.
at UnrealBuildTool.RulesAssembly.CreateTargetRules(String TargetName, UnrealTargetPlatform Platform, UnrealTargetConfiguration Configuration, String Architecture, FileReference ProjectFile, CommandLineArguments Arguments, ILogger Logger, Boolean IsTestTarget)
at UnrealBuildTool.ProjectFileGenerator.AddProjectsForAllTargets(PlatformProjectGeneratorCollection PlatformProjectGenerators, List1 AllGames, List1 AllTargetFiles, String[] Arguments, ProjectFile& EngineProject, List1 GameProjects, Dictionary2 ProgramProjects, Dictionary`2 RulesAssemblies, ILogger Logger)
at UnrealBuildTool.ProjectFileGenerator.GenerateProjectFiles(PlatformProjectGeneratorCollection PlatformProjectGenerators, String[] Arguments, ILogger Logger)
at UnrealBuildTool.GenerateProjectFilesMode.Execute(CommandLineArguments Arguments, ILogger Logger)
at UnrealBuildTool.UnrealBuildTool.Main(String[] ArgumentsArray)
WriteFileIfChanged() wrote 0 changed files of 0 requested writes.
Timeline:

[ 0.000]
0.000
[ 6.174]
```

I have tried finding similar issues but couldn't find anything please help